# PDF DeviceN color space with names array

Tags: pdf, color-space

I've been trying this PDF file: https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-library/files/730494/problem4.pdf

I'm trying to figure out how the names array in the DeviceN color space works.
For example this:

```
[ /DeviceN [ /C4 /C5 /C6 /C7 ] /DeviceCMYK 44 0 R ]
```

The names array:

```
[ /C4 /C5 /C6 /C7 ]
```

I clearly see that there are 4 values provided in the array, probably representing CMYK in some way because the alternateSpace is DeviceCMYK. 
But how exactly are these array values evaluated?

by reading the pdf reference 1.7 on DeviceN it is not clear to me what you need to do with these C4, C5, C6, C7 values.

Do you need to check the output device to see if the color names C4, C5, C6 and C7 are known on the output device? Which will be in most cases unknown, resulting in the usage of the alternateSpace?
Or does each value (C4, C5, ...) need to be looked up in the Resources? (but how will it work for C3 in this pdf as C3 will reference to itself?)

Could somebody clarify the steps that will be done to get he correct color.
so far I think it goes like this:

1. DeviceN color space reads the array: [ /DeviceN [ /C4 /C5 /C6 /C7 ] /DeviceCMYK 44 0 R ]
2. First the names array is checked if the names exist on the output device
3. We did not find C4 (and also not the other names), so we will use the alternativeSpace
4. The alternative space to use is DeviceCMYK
5. We check the resources if there is a DefaultCMYK available
6. Yes there is, we remap the DeviceCMYK to DefaultCMYK
7. We create color based on DefaultCMYK

is this correct?

Comment: *"so far I think it goes like this:"* - I'm missing in step 3 a description of how the **DeviceN** components actually are mapped to alternativeSpace components. Here there is a choice between using the *tintTransform* (in 44 0 R in your example) or the *attributes* (not present in your example)... or even the program's own blending algorithms if merely the target device does not know the names but the program does know them.